# Is there a json api call to get the tags for an entity in orocrm?

Tags: api, orocrm

I wish to get the tags for the contact entities in orocrm vi the jsonapi.  How do I get the tags as no tag relation is returned in the response?

I have found in the legacy rest api how to add tags.  But still no way to retrieve the tags for an entity.

Comment: tag is sort of dynamic field, it does not have direct doctrine relation specified so I'm not sure if there is any possibility to specify it in `api.yml` configuration, I can think of some `Controller` listener maybe that changes the body of the response

Comment: actually, there is possibility to define Nested Association for class-id identifier - https://github.com/oroinc/platform/blob/master/src/Oro/Bundle/ApiBundle/Resources/doc/how_to.md#configure-a-nested-association